Installer stops on winehq installation: upgrade from 22,04 to 24,04
The installer says a new version is available. When I upgrade, then the installation stops and outputs that the winehq is not a secure source to install from.
I have tried to install via Terminal: sudo apt update but the same thing happens.
What is wrong?

Please edit your question and provide the full output of sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade.  Do not post screenshots, copy and paste the text with proper formatting.

That sounds like you have added the WINhq repository to allow a more advanced copy of WINE? (Ubuntu does offer and older version of wine). You could try to disable the repository 'Software&Updates->OtherSoftware' but you might also have to remove the loaded software as well (?). Once you have 24.04 installed you could then re-add the WINhq advanced stuff.

NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F, E:Arkivet »https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease« er ikke underskrevet. this is the message I get when trying to installe 24,4 lts. I have uninstalled wine
